# How to remove space in section title at KOMA-Script

Tags: sectioning, numbering, koma-script, sections-paragraphs

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{adforn}


\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
        \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
               {\adforn{30} {#3}. {#4} \adforn{58}}
        }
    {{\hskip#2#3}{#4}}%
}\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{ABC}

\end{document}
```

The output is this:
[image]

I want it will be: **1. ABC** and not **1 . ABC** *(no space between the "1" and the ".")*.
It is possible? and if it's possible, how can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: sorry, I am not able to compile your MWE (Font OrnementsADF not found). Just a guess: try to terminate every line that might be fragile with a `%`: `\ifstr{#1}{section}{%
               {\adforn{30} {#3}. {#4} \adforn{58}}%
        }%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro `\sectionformat` contains an `\enskip` at the end. You can redefine it without that:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{adforn}

\def\sectionformat{\thesection\autodot}% \enskip
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
        \ifstr{#1}{section}{%
               {\adforn{30} {#3}. {#4} \adforn{58}}
        }
    {{\hskip#2#3}{#4}}%
}\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{ABC}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you!! What is the `\csname` command?

Comment: @heblyx It allows you to use a control sequence (_a.k.a._ macro) by its name. One expansion of `\csname thesection\endcsname` gives `\thesection`. If you simply use `\thesection` it will work as well. The `\csname` thingy is just for dynamically creating these formatting commands.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik - Using the `\csname ... \endcsname` machinery would seem to be overkill here. Maybe replace `\csname thesection\endcsname \autodot` with `\thesection.\autodot`? :-)

Comment: @Mico Indeed, unnecessary complication. Done :)

Comment: Note: This could result in two `.`, if `\autodot` results in adding a `.`. And IMHO the KOMA-Script guide recommends to add number format parts like the end dot to `\sectionformat` instead of `\sectionlinesformat`. See my answer about how to do this.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Your answer is, of course, the proper way to do this :) I suspected KOMA had some better way of doing that, but I didn't know better.

Answer (score 4):

You should reduce group braces to a minimum and add the `.` either to the `\sectionformat`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{adforn}

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\thesection.\enskip}% replaced \autodot by .
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}%
    {\adforn{30} #3#4 \adforn{58}}%
    {\hskip#2#3#4}%
}\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{ABC}

\end{document}
```

or select `numbers=withdot` to add the dot to all section levels:

```
\documentclass[numbers=enddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{adforn}

\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}%
    {\adforn{30} #3#4 \adforn{58}}%
    {\hskip#2#3#4}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{ABC}

\end{document}
```

Both examples result in:

[image: O 1. ABC o]

Note: You should not combine a `\autodot` in `\sectionformat` with a hard coded `.` (neither in `\autodot` nor on `\sectionlinesformat` where it is misplaced by specification), because this could result in two dots.

Please have a look to the [KOMA-Script manual](https://komascript.de/scrguien) for the default of `\sectionformat` and the meaning of `numbers=withdot`, `\sectionformat` and `\autodot`.

BTW: The `\makeatother` in your example is also not necessary and should be removed (so I did).

Off-Topic: You should also avoid possible spurious white spaces by newlines after `}` or `{` and by real spaces in the middle of the code.

---

As a comment claims that this does not work with `hebrew`:

```
\documentclass[numbers=enddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
\usepackage{adforn}

\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}%
    {\adforn{30} #3#4 \adforn{58}}%
    {\hskip#2#3#4}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{גדה}

\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
\usepackage{adforn}

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\thesection.\enskip}% replaced \autodot by .
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}%
    {\adforn{30} #3#4 \adforn{58}}%
    {\hskip#2#3#4}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{גדה}

\end{document}
```

both result in:

[image: o הדג .1 O]

which seem to be correct for using RL.

Comment: Your solution is good, but I'm not sure it's good for me. Because I'm Hebrew user - the dot is always at wrong side... at Hebrew it shuold be ".1" and not "1."

Comment: It is possible?

Comment: @heblyx Cannot reproduce this. See my `hebrew` example.

Comment: I will replace it. Thank you!!